# Design a generic numeric comparator function using expl3 working for strings, counters, numexpr, dimexpr

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion, programming, comparison

I would like to design a generic `compare` function **between numbers**, ideally expandable with the following signature:

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\compare}{r[] m m m m m}{%CODE HERE%}
```

that would be used in the following syntax :

```
\compare[!=]{lhs}{rhs}{true branch}{false branch}{invalid branch}
```

where the left-hand side `lhs` and right-hand side `rhs` would be fully expanded before being processed and where first parameter (also fully expanded) could be `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`. And I would like the function to work for:

- counters
- lengths
- numexpr, dimexpr, etc...
- strings when the string reprents a number (so the string `023` is the number 23)

(the invalid branch would typically be triggered when comparing length with `plus` and `minus` terms like `10pt plus 1.5pt minus 1.5pt` with `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=` operators, or when the comparison simply does not make sense) so that a user could type:

```
\compare[==]{\mycounter}{\othercounter}{true}{false}{invalid}
\compare[<]{\mycounter}{12}{true}{false}{invalid}
\compare[>=]{15.8}{\mycounter}{true}{false}{invalid}
\compare[>=]{\mylength}{\otherlength}{true}{false}{invalid}
\compare[>=]{\mylength}{14.3}{true}{false}{invalid}
\compare[\myoperator]{\mylength}{14.3}{true}{false}{invalid}
```

and so on... I need the resulting code to work on typical versions of TeX dating back from 5 years ago (~2018) (so no use of super duper recent functionalities).

---

Here is a test code:

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\compare}{r[] m m m m m}{%
    % CODE HERE
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@@yoperator}{<}
\newcommand{\@myoperatory}{\@@myoperator}
\newcommand{\myoperator}{\@myoperator}
\newcommand{\@@myintstring}{12}
\newcommand{\@myintstring}{\@@myintstring}
\newcommand{\myintstring}{\@myintstring}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{15}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{10pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
\newdimen\mydim
\mydim=1cm
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\compare[==]{23}{24}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[!=]{23}{24}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{23}{24}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<=]{23}{24}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[>]{23}{24}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[>=]{23}{24}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[\myoperator]{23}{24}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[\myoperator]{\myintstring}{\myintstring}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[\myoperator]{\myintstring}{10}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[\myoperator]{10}{\myintstring}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{\mylength}{12pt}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{\mylength}{\mydim}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[==]{\mydim}{\mydim}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[==]{\mydim}{12pt}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

**QUESTION:** How to create such a function? (if it's too complicated to make it expandable, doing a non-expandable function is ok)

Comment: I see one problem...consider these two items to compare `{23}` and `{023}`.  As strings, they compare false; as numbers, they compare true.  What did you have in mind for such a case?

Comment: Oh I will modify the question. The compare I have in mind interprets everything as numbers. So the string 023 and the number 23 should compare equal.

Comment: I use `\fpeval` for routine comparisons. For the benefit of readers here, is there something your proposed code would do, that `\fpeval` cannot already do? I assume the answer is yes.

Comment: When used in the context of TeX's *<number>*-quantities, `\dimexpr` and lengths are integer numbers which denote the value of the length measured in the unit sp (scaled point). But TeX's *<number>*-quantities can be integers only. Do you need the thing to work out for floating point numbers, too? I did not yet hear of a reliable test whether a sequence of tokens forms a valid TeX *<number>*-quantitiy.

Comment: In case the tokens forming some component of some test-argument initiate an expansion-based algorithm such a test would include checking whether that algorithm terminates at all/terminates without error message. That is not trivial in TeX.