# Branch to something when an expression cannot be evaluated by fpeval

Tags: expl3, programming, compilation-error, fp, floating-point

I would like to design a `\comparator` expandable command that relies on `fpeval` that has 3 branches:

- *true branch* when the comparison is equal to 1
- *false branch* when the comparison is equal to zero
- *invalid branch* when the comparison cannot be performed (instead of returning a compilation error)

Here is the current code I use:

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\compare}{r[] m m m m m}{
    \compare_evaluation:eeennn{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
}
\cs_new:Nn \compare_evaluation:nnnnnn{
    \compare_result:ennn{\fpeval{#2 #1 #3}}{#4}{#5}{#6}
}
\cs_new:Nn \compare_result:nnnn{
    \str_case:nnTF{#1}{
        {0}{#3}
        {1}{#2}
    }{}{#4}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \compare_evaluation:nnnnnn{eeennn}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \compare_result:nnnn{ennn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\compare[<]{1.5}{2.5}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{2.5}{1.5}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{xx}{xx}{true}{false}{invalid} \\ % CRASHES
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which, of course, crashes for the last line of the test.

**QUESTION:** How to make it compilable and branch correctly (here to print `invalid`)?

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of your earlier question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708469/design-a-generic-numeric-comparator-function-using-expl3-working-for-strings-co

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The current question is a sub-question of the earlier one, indirectly. This question is actually better, since it focuses the issue down to a branch-on-error, rather than to a more comprehensive substitute for `\fpeval`. Maybe. This really looks like a job for Lua, if it can be done at all.

Comment: are luatex-only solutions acceptable or do you need this to work in tex (which has no error catching mechanism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If expandability is not a requirement, you can check the syntax using a regex

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}

% These only needed in old latex releases
% \usepackage{xparse}
% \usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\compare}{r[] m m m m m}{
    \compare_evaluation:eeennn{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
}
\cs_new:Nn \compare_evaluation:nnnnnn{
  \regex_match:nnTF
  {^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?([eE][0-9]+)?@@@[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?([eE][0-9]+)?$}
  {#2@@@#3}
  {
    \compare_result:ennn{\fpeval{#2 #1 #3}}{#4}{#5}{#6}
  }
  {#6}
  }
\cs_new:Nn \compare_result:nnnn{
    \str_case:nnTF{#1}{
        {0}{#3}
        {1}{#2}
    }{}{#4}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \compare_evaluation:nnnnnn{eeennn}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \compare_result:nnnn{ennn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\compare[<]{1.5}{2.5}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{2.5}{1.5}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{2.5e2}{15e3}{true}{false}{invalid} \\
\compare[<]{xx}{xx}{true}{false}{invalid} \\ % CRASHES
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

here I assumed `@@@` was safe to use as a separator, you could use regex on the two arguments separately, or use a custom command tken, but this shows the basic idea. Also the regex may not be exactly the same syntax as l3fp in edge cases (and doesn't cover fp expressions) but catches the main literal syntaxes.

Comment: "expandable command"

Comment: @Skillmon you don't always get what you asked for (and the previous version of the question said expandable was preferred but non expandable would do)

Comment: Didn't know the previous version, sorry. I'd say the question is pretty vague though. Are `#2` and `#3` expected to be single numbers or arbitrary `\fpeval` expressions? The latter can't be parsed by regular expressions, I'm afraid, so I'd say without reimplementing `l3fp` this isn't possible...

Comment: @Skillmon yes I did mention failure to match expressions in the answer, I should probably have mentioned it's not expandable, I'll add.